# Why strategy.openprofit only shows for the previous candle?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm using version 5 and trying to display a label that shows the current live unrealized loss/profit. I made it so that previous labels of the same get deleted and only the last one remains printed. The problem is that instead of showing the current live candle, it prints the previous one after close. I provided an image for previewing where the label prints and this is an example of the code:

[TradingView Chart Label Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHq1n.jpg)

```
//Colors
ColorLongSL = color.purple
ColorLongTP = color.blue
ColorShortSL = color.orange
ColorShortTP = #ff79b8

//Is there a long or short position open?
longopen = strategy.position_size>0 
shortopen = strategy.position_size<0

//Convert current loss or profit to string text
unrealizedL = ('Unrealized Loss -$' + str.tostring(math.round(strategy.openprofit*-1)))
unrealizedP = ('Unrealized Profit $' + str.tostring(math.round(strategy.openprofit)))

//Print Labels for live unrealized loss/profit

//For Long
currentLLoss = label.new(strategy.openprofit<0 and longopen ? bar_index : na, na, unrealizedL, style=label.style_label_up, color=ColorLongSL, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
currentLProfit = label.new(strategy.openprofit>0 and longopen ? bar_index : na, na, unrealizedP, style=label.style_label_down, color=ColorLongTP, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
label.delete(currentLLoss[1]) 
label.delete(currentLProfit[1])

//For Short 
currentSProfit = label.new(strategy.openprofit>0 and shortopen ? bar_index : na, na, unrealizedP, style=label.style_label_up, color=ColorShortTP, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
currentSLoss = label.new(strategy.openprofit<0 and shortopen ? bar_index : na, na, unrealizedL, style=label.style_label_down, color=ColorShortSL, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
label.delete(currentSLoss[1])
label.delete(currentSProfit[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default strategies are calculated on bars' closes. If you really want real-time data, you should set `calc_on_every_tick` property of your `strategy()` to `true`.

**Note:** Instead of creating and deleting labels all the time, you can have one label for each and just update their position and text using the `label.set_x`, `label.set_y` and `label.set_text` functions. This will improve your script's performance.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! And good idea about label.set. I want it to be as efficient as possible.